# Saving feeds permanently in the iphone app

Tags: iphone

I want to make a favorites button in my tab bar controller which permanently saves that live feed in my app. the feed description is in text. So basically i want to make an array of those texts which are saved permanently in my favorites table view.
How should I start with it. Do i have to make another class for it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If feed already stored in NSArray then just store in disk using
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag

You can even load the data back using NSArray API.